# What is correct way to write a condition using when in Jenkinsfile?

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am trying to write `when` statement in the single `stage` block in `Jenkinsfile`. I have tried to write as below. I know it's not the correct way to write. It's a declarative pipeline script. The pipeline expects only a single `when` block. How can I combine both of my `when` blocks and write as a single `when`.

```
stages{
    stage('Approve Dev Deployment') {
                agent { label 'docker-kitchensink-slave' }
                when {
                    anyOf {
                        expression {
                            return (env.GIT_BRANCH.equals('master') || env.GIT_BRANCH.startsWith('hotfix-'))
                        }
                    }
                }
                when {
                    expression {
                        input message: 'Deploy test?'
                        return true
                    }
                    beforeAgent true
                }
                steps{
                            approveDeployment()
                }
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Write function with the conditions outside the pipeline scope and use the function as a condition.

```
def checkcondition(){
    your_condition
}

stages{
    stage('Approve Dev Deployment') {
                agent { label 'docker-kitchensink-slave' }
                when { checkcondition() }
                steps{
                    approveDeployment()
                }
            }
}
```

Comment: I also want the input message in the `when`. How can I write both the `branching condition` and the `input message` in a single `when`.

Comment: I'm not sure what you trying to do, but if input works in when you can store the input value in a variable and use it in the condition with `if else`

Comment: maybe somthing like this inside the check function:
 `boolean deploy = false 

def inputvalue = input message: 'Deploy test?'

if ( env.GIT_BRANCH.equals('master') || env.GIT_BRANCH.startsWith('hotfix-') ){
    deploy = true
}
if (inputvalue){
    deploy == true
}
`